# c++ const in the argument

Tags: c++, c++11

why this code shows error while compiling?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void foo(int& x){
   // cout<<x;
}

int main(){
    //int x=3;
    foo(3);
    return 0;
}
```

but by changing the argument to const it compiles properly

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void foo(const int& x){
   // cout<<x;
}

int main(){
    //int x=3;
    foo(3);
    return 0;
}
```

but i am still passing an integer so how does it compiles by adding const in the argument?

Comment: The usual purpose of using a reference parameter is so you can modify the caller's variable by assigning to the parameter. What should be modified when you have a reference to `3` instead of a variable?

Answer (score 2):

`int& x` can be changed, so it can't get reference to `const int` like 3.

`const int& x` can't be changed and type is perfectly match to `const int` like 3, so why you expect it to fail?